# Jsp page not redirecting to another jsp page

Tags: java, spring, jsp, redirect, controller

I know this question has already been answered but i have a specific issue, when i return a redirect from a controller to another controller which returns a view, the view is sent as a response. I'm not able to display this JSP page sent in the response. The preview of the response is exactly what i want to display in the window. I'm able to do this with help of Ajax but i want my controller to redirect to the page.

```
@RequestMapping(value="validate")
public String validate(String validateLogin){
    System.out.println("Validation begin");
    System.out.println(validateLogin);
    if(directoryService.validateUser(validateLogin)){
        return "redirect:welcome";
    }else{
        return "/index";
    }
```

redirects to

```
@RequestMapping(value="welcome")
public String justToRedirect(){
    if(CurrentUser.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
        System.out.println("User type is Admin");
        return "/welcomeAdmin";
    }else if(CurrentUser.getUserType().equalsIgnoreCase("user")){
        System.out.println("User type is Client");
        return "/welcomeUser";
    }else{
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand anything to your explanation. What are you trying to do, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: My validate controller redirects to justToRedirect controller which returns a view: welcomeAdmin or welcomeUser depending on the validations. The return view comes in form of response but donot display in the window ie the view is not updated @JBNizet

Comment: How are you invoking this controller? By typing its URL in the address bar of your browser? By making an AJAX request?

Comment: ajax request, Thanks alot for answering!

Comment: If you're using AJAX, then your JavaScript callback is responsible to deal with the response you get from the server. So the problem is the JS code, not the server-side code.

Comment: success:function(response){
      console.log("success");
      $('#username-error').slideUp(100);
      $('input#username').css("border","");
      $('#error').hide();
      
      //window.location.href = response;
      
      
     },

Comment: Thanks alot for your support, i appreciate it. I have posted JS code which is a success function that redirects the window to response url. Is there any better of doing it.